# :contains issue on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, contains

It seems that `jQuery :contains` selector does not work on IE8.

Please see following example on IE - **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/p3W4x/23/)**

JS:

```
$('table tr td:contains(" + ")').each( function(){
        $(this).addClass('url');
});
```

Comment: I can't see your fiddle as jsFiddle is being slow as usual, but try escaping the `+`, like this: `$('table tr td:contains(" \+ ")')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - it wont help using an escape character

Comment: You start by telling us that the selector with spaces doesn't work, thetn your update tells us not to use spaces. Which is it?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - sorry, it is not an update - this is an alternative solution to the problem.

Comment: @NewUser: Please don't write answers in the question. Write them as answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the spaces in your TDs to HTML entities (`&nbsp;`)

for `$('table tr td:contains(" + ")')` to work. (Same JS/CSS)

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;+&nbsp;</td>
         <td> 1 </td>
         <td> 3 </td>
         <td> 6 </td>
         <td> 7 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However it will fail on modern browsers, so the solution is to replace the entities for those browsers. Just prepend this snippet before yours, it will do the job.

```
if( !($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 10) ){
    $('table tr td').each(function(){
        $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' ') );
    });
}
```

Comment: IE8 will ignores the whitespace, so in fact, it is "+" not " + ". But in JS, you can use :contains(" + ") as well, not need to convert whitespace to HTML entity

Comment: Using `&nbsp;+&nbsp;` will work on IE, but will now work on FF or Chrome. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler solution to the `IE8 :contains` issue:

Make sure you are **not using the space** inside the string, e.g

`$('table tr td:contains("+")')` **will work** even if your html have spaces`<td> + </td>`